# AngularJS routing doesnt work in Visual Studio

Tags: angularjs

I am running my AngularJS code in VS 2015. The routing just doesn't work. I tried everything but I get the url like below in the address bar of the browser when I click on the hyperlink "Add" and nothing gets displayed and same issue with other hyperlinks also. Please advise.

```
       "http://localhost:21530/Index.html#!#Add"
```

Here is the code:

HTML File:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="MyApp">

<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/Main/Home.js"></script>
</head>`enter code here`

<body>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#Home">Homes</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Add">Add</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Edit">Edit</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Delete">Delete</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ng-view>
        </ng-view>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Home.js:

```
/// <reference path="../angular.js" />
var MyApp = angular.module("MyApp", ["ngRoute"]);

MyApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when("/Add", {
            templateUrl: "Views/Add.html",
            controller: "AddController"
        })
        .when("/Edit", {
            templateUrl: "Views/Edit.html",
            controller: "EditController"
        })
        .when("/Delete", {
            templateUrl: "Views/Delete.html",
            controller: "DeleteController"
        })
        .when("/Home", {
            templateUrl: "Views/Home.html",
            controller: "HomesController"
        });
});

MyApp.controller("AddController", function($scope) {
    $scope.message = "Add Screen";
});
MyApp.controller("EditController", function($scope) {
    $scope.message = "Edit Screen";
});
MyApp.controller("DeleteController", function($scope) {
    $scope.message = "Delete Screen";
});
MyApp.controller("HomeController", function($scope) {
    $scope.message = "Home Screen";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

change all your href as below :

```
<div>
      <ul>
       <li><a href="#/Home">Homes</a></li>
       <li><a href="#/Add">Add</a></li>
       <li><a href="#/Edit">Edit</a></li>
       <li><a href="#/Delete">Delete</a></li>
     </ul>
    <ng-view>
    </ng-view>
</div>
```

Comment: Tried this, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try to activate the HTML5 mode (`$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`) in  `MyApp.config`.

See the official doc: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#example

Answer (score 0):

`MyApp.config([`**'$routeProvider'**`, function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
    when("/Add", {
        templateUrl: "Views/Add.html",
         controller: "AddController"
          })
    .when("/Edit", {
    templateUrl: "Views/Edit.html",
    controller: "EditController"
          })
    .when("/Delete", {
     templateUrl: "Views/Delete.html",
     controller: "DeleteController"
      })

   .when("/Home", {
    templateUrl: "Views/Home.html",
    controller: "HomesController"
     });
     }]);`

You have to inject **$routeprovider** first. The $routeprovider inside function() you have written is just the parameter name which can be anything.

Please see that you open and close the square brackets properly.. Try Running the application now. If it doesnt work, also try **`<a ng-href="#Add">Add</a>`** inside the nav li.

Hope it works for you :) .